# async function return array empty

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native, asynchronous

I'm using sqlite3 to fetch data from local testDB. The fetching and parsing is done in dataquery.js. getAllPoints is supposed to fetch all the database records.In camOverLay.js class async testcallfunctions is using await for promise to be fulfilled from getAllPoints in dataquery.js. When I try to print out the return value from the async function it shows null although there are ten items. It seems like the await is not waiting till the promise is fulfilled.

```
[![debugger][1]][1]
dataquery.js 

import SQLite from "react-native-sqlite-storage";

const db = SQLite.openDatabase({name:"testDB", createFromLocation:1})

function parsePoints(row){
  var longitude = row.data_longitude.slice(3,-3);
  var latitude  = row.date_latitude.slice(3,-3);
  var price     = row.price.slice(1);
  var address   = row.address;

  const obj = {longitude:longitude,
               latitude:latitude,
                address: address,
               price:  price}
  return obj
}

module.exports = {
  getAllPoints :async function(){
    return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
      var agg_data = [];
      SQLite.DEBUG(true);
      SQLite.enablePromise(true);
      db.transaction(tx=>{
        tx.executeSql(
          'SELECT * FROM listinginfo LIMIT 10',
          [], (tx, results)=>{
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for(let i = 0; i < len ; i++){
              let row = results.rows.item(i);
              obj = parsePoints(row);
              console.log("this is obj")
              console.log(obj)
              console.log(obj.price)
              agg_data.push(obj);
              console.log("this is agg_data");
              console.log(agg_data.length);
            }
            });
       });
      res(agg_data);
      return res
    });
  }
}
```

camOverLay.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, FlatList,TouchableOpacity,Text, ListView,View, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import dataquery from './../utils/dataquery';

function callfunction(){
console.log("this is a test call for utils");

}
export default class camOverLay extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
   this.testcallfunction()
   // callfunction()
  }
  async testcallfunction(){
    let p1 = await dataquery.getAllPoints();
    console.log("this is the p1")
    console.log(p1)
    console.log(p1.length);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>AR Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you are resolving your Promise (`res(agg_data);`) outside the callback that populates the result i.e. the callback to `tx.executeSql` - try calling `res(agg_data)` just after the for loop that builds it

Comment: also, no need to make `getAllPoints` async, as you a) never use await, and b) returning a `new Promise`